# Hide AppBarLayout Toolbar and BottomNavigation while scrolling

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

For bottom bar navigation, using a library [ahbottomnavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) .
Where I want to hide both bottom bar and toolbar on scroll, with following code (and demo from library github) I could hide bottom bar, but cant hide toolbar.

If I add "app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"" to toolbar it hides bottom bar completely like in following case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/primary"
      android:elevation="4dp"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
      app:titleTextAppearance="@style/title_font"
      app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigationViewPager
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:elevation="4dp"
      app:selectedBackgroundVisible="false" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this case, Only toolbar shows up, and bottom bar completely disappears
Where as

Regards . :)

Comment: Have you try bottombar without using the library. Maybe the issue occur because that library